# How to get Facebook access token from Graph API Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to alert the `access_token` with a simple function but I'm getting `undefined` I'm following their syntax but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**javascript**

```
   function logMe() {  
    FB.login(function(){
      FB.api('/me/accounts', {fields: 'access_token'}, function(response) {
      var accessToken = response.data.access_token;
      alert(accessToken);
        } );
    }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
    }
```

Comment: Well, `response` is an object. Within it is data. Do `console.log(response)` to see its structure.

Comment: Do you have a correct API-Key?

Answer (score 0):

With `/me/accounts`, you get an array of pages you manage - not just one entry:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', {fields: 'access_token'}, (response) => {
    if (response && response.data) {
        for (let i = 0, count = response.data.length; i < count; i++) {
            console.log(respose.data[i].access_token);
        }
    }
});
```

This would be the API endpoint to get the access token for a specific page:

```
/[page-id]?fields=access_token
```

Comment: I know I did write a code like this to get the pages. I didn't think I had to do this again once they picked the page. The array only contains one page tho. Do I still need to do this every time, even after they already selected the one page they want us to manage?

Comment: in that case, you have to do another api call. i will update my answer.

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis in the line with the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

With luschn response above this is the final answer

```
   function logMe() {
    var page_id=document.getElementById('page_id').value;
    FB.login(function(){
      FB.api('/' + page_id + '?fields=access_token', function(response) {
       //get access token
       var accessToken = response.access_token;
      console.log(accessToken);
        } );
    }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
    }
```